# AVPlayer addObserver message was received but not handled

Tags: swift, avplayer

Ive been trying to add an observer to listen to AVPlayer's "timeControlStatus", mostly taken dirrectly from Apple's example;
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/media_playback_and_selection/observing_playback_state

I created a sperate class called Play and im calling the below from the ViewController

```
Play().playMusic(url: url!)
```

Class Play()

```
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

var player: AVPlayer! = nil
var playerItemContext = 0

class Play: AVPlayer {
  
    func playMusic(url : URL) {
        
        let asset = AVAsset(url: url)
        let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
        if player == nil {
                player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
            if player.status.rawValue == 0 {
                player.play()
               player.addObserver(player, forKeyPath: "timeControlStatus", options: [.old, .new], context: &playerItemContext)
                }
                } else {
                player.replaceCurrentItem(with: playerItem)
                player.play()
                }
    }
  
    override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?,
                               of object: Any?,
                               change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?,
                               context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {


        // Only handle observations
        guard context == &playerItemContext else {
            super.observeValue(forKeyPath: keyPath,
                               of: object,
                               change: change,
                               context: context)
            return
        }
        if keyPath == "timeControlStatus" { print("Result") }
    }
}
```

The above always crashes with;

```
<AVPlayer: 0x6000030a4770>: An -observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context: message was received but not handled.
Key path: timeControlStatus
Observed object: <AVPlayer: 0x6000030a4770>
Change: {
    kind = 1;
    new = 1;
    old = 1;
}
Context: 0x1003f3e98'
```

If I remove the 'addObserver', the code acts as intended and plays the audio file, the weird thing is, if move all the observer code from the Play class over to ViewContoller it works? what gives?.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is merely that when you move the code to the view controller, the view controller persists. It is a stable object living in the view controller hierarchy. So it lives long enough to do some work.

But on the other hand, in this line:

```
Play().playMusic(url: url!)
```

...the Play instance is created and immediately goes out of existence again, like a quantum virtual particle. It doesn't live long enough to be there when the playing proceeds. Hence the crash: you have allowed the observer to go out of existence too soon.

If you wanted your Play instance to persist, you would need to *assign* it to some long-lived variable, such as a property of your view controller.

Comment: Also please note that to do KVO you should not be calling `addObserver(_:forKeyPath:...)`. It is outdated and dangerous (as you have discovered). Use `observe(_:options:changeHandler:)`.